# Protect fields from GraphQL querying

Tags: graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I have this User model in TypeGraphQL with TypeGoose:

```
@index({ email: 1 })
@queryMethod(findByEmail)
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ required: true })
  email: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ required: true })
  password: string;
}
```

But what currently one could query the (albeit encrypted) password using the GraphQL querying. Is there a way to make the password field not queryable?

Comment: Just remove the `@Field(() => String)` annotation from the password property.

Comment: @W.S. this is the correct answer. You should reply with an answer that we can vote for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @W.S. pointed out, removing the `@Field(() => String)` annotation from the password property made the field not queryable.